# JSOM: get_isSiteAdmin () is not distinguishing between users and administrator of site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, administration

```
                if (user.get_isSiteAdmin()) {
                  document.cookie = "licence=yes";

                }
```

I am using user.get_isSiteAdmin() but its always giving value false I can not give

> "Site Collection - Full Control"

is there any other way to get site administrator ?

Answer (score 0):

You could check your site administrator here:
[image]
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-administrators

Comment: I have already checked site-admin there its giving value false when I get site admin int his condition
     ` if (user.get_isSiteAdmin()) {
                  document.cookie = "licence=yes";
                }`

Actually I want to redirect to site admin on specific page and other user to on other page its redirecting both on same page